# Laravel form not sending request of dynamically generated content

Tags: php, jquery, laravel

I have a form like this:

```
<form class="form-horizontal" role="form" method="POST" name="myform" id="myform" action="{{ url('/mypage/') }}">
        {{ csrf_field() }}
<div id="somecontent">
</div>
<div id="abutton">
</div>
</form>
```

Then some Jquery like this:

```
 $('#somecontent').html('<select class="form-control" id="myselect"  form="my"><option value="1">Hello</option><option value="2">World</option></select>');
```

And then I add a button like this:

```
button = $('<button type="submit" form="myform" class="btn btn-theme">Send</button>');

$('#abutton').html(button);
```

And I also change the action dynamically:

```
 $("#myform").attr("action","/mypage/" + item_id);
```

Then I got this in the web file:

```
Route::post('/mypage/{item_id}','mycontroller@do_something');
```

And then do this in the controller:

```
public function do_something($item_id,Request $request){
dd($request);
}
```

But the $request is empty, it does not contain the value selected in the dynamically generated select.

Any ideas why?

Comment: why are you using item_id as parameter, its already in the request.

Comment: @Sagar they are 2 different things.

Comment: you haven't added `name` attribute of select, add name attribute and see it will populate into `$request`

Comment: @PandhiBhaumik Bingo. You may want to post it as answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you haven't added `name` attribute of select, add name attribute and see it will populate into `$request`.

Try below code.

```
 $('#somecontent').html('<select name="select_name" class="form-control" id="myselect"  form="my"><option value="1">Hello</option><option value="2">World</option></select>');
```